# How to make the python program work in the background

Tags: python

how can i make my program run silently when running? I would like it to leave no trace and nothing to appear visually, in C# we say '' Silent Load '', but I don't know how it works in Python
obs : i use pycharm for coding

Comment: If you're using a bash termnial, you could do this `python file.py > log_file.txt 2>&1 &`. Just adding the `&` will silence it `python file.py &`

Comment: how can i put this in pycharm before converting to .EXE?

Comment: What are you using to create the .exe? If you're using pyinstaller there is a --noconsole option.

Comment: work bro, very tnks

Comment: No problem. Can you add pyinstaller and that it is an exe to the question and also mark this as a working answer? It will make it easier for others to find the same answer and get your rep up.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using pyinstaller there is a --noconsole option. Docs are [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#windows-and-mac-os-x-specific-options)